# Create object in place

Tags: c#

Can I create an object in place? What I mean is when I have the following class which takes two parameters

```
class Foo {
    public Foo(int x, int y) {}
}
```

and the following method which takes a `Foo` object

```
public void do(Foo foo) {}
```

can I then write something like this

```
do({1,2});
```

instead of this

```
do(new Foo(1,2));
```

This would be especially helpful if Foo had a really long name and was surrounded by several namespaces.

Comment: "*can I then write something like this*" - no, you can't. There are no such a "shorthands" for object creation in C#.

Comment: Maybe if you are recoding the .net C# Compiler you can ;-)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: Thanks, that's a shame. I'm coming from a C++ background, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @gartenriese You can't do that in C++ either.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: [Sure I can](https://ideone.com/CYR6AP).

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible.
However if the problem is long names you could try a using alias directive.

```
using F = A.Very.Long.Namespace.and.classname.FooBarThing;

// ...
List<Bar> list;

// ...
list.Add(new F(1,2));
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

No you cannot. There's only a construct for property/field initialization, e.g.:

`new Foo() { a = 2, b = 3 }`.

**Longer answer**

It could beg the question "why not"? Well, I would consider this scenario:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{ 
    public Bar(int a, int b) : Foo(a, b) {}
}

// ...
List<Bar> list;

// ...
list.Add({1,2});
```

Now, you at some point you decide that it's a bit strange to have a 'Bar' there in the list, so you change the signature of the list to `List<Foo> list;`. Your code will now break, because the other constructor is now the 'default'.

Comment: Why would it break? If the other constructor has the same parameters, it should not change?

Comment: If the constructor of Foo needs to be called as `Foo(b,a)` you have the bug.

Comment: @rene: That's not how the answer is written though.

Comment: @gartenriese You'll end up with a list of Bar objects in the first case, and a list of Foo objects in the second case. I'm assuming they're not the same.